# MySQL producer consumer with multiple select threads

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, locking

I've to following situation:

There is a table containing different "jobs" to process and several worker threads consuming those jobs. 
As I don't want to delete those jobs once finished, I'll just set a "complete" flag for that record.

So in fact I've the following workflow (for each processing thread)

1. Select 1st record which is not complete
2. Process job
3. Set "complete" flag

How do I prevent other threads from consuming the same job (as setting it to "complete" will take a while). Also just updating the "complete" flag in the 2nd step will cause some jobs to be processed twice as there might be a big number of threads processing a small ammount of jobs.

The easiest way would be to lock just the record (yes, I'm using InnoDB), so that other threads aren't able to read just that singe record set. This is easily be doable via an "FOR UPDATE", but that will lock the entire table for future selects and all other "FOR UPDATE" selects have to wait until the 1st one has completed.

Can anyone tell me, how to solve such a situation without delaying all other threads? So in fact a select (can also be limited by LIMIT 1) should only "see" non locked rows ...

A example table structure will look like

```
JobID | completed
123   | 0
124   | 1
125   | 0
```

with around 10-50 threads doing a simple

```
SELECT JobID from jobs WHERE completed = 0;
UPDATE jobs SET completed = 1 WHERE JobID = ?;
```

Thx for any tips and tricks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a practical solution for you, one that I have seen implemented in a project at my workplace. Instead of using just 0 and 1 for incomplete and completed, expand your set to include more cases.

Let's call that column **status**. Here are the different values of that column and the corresponding states of the job.

1. When status is 0, the job has not been picked up by any worker thread.
2. When status is 1, the job has been picked up by a worker thread and is under process.
3. When status is 2, the job has failed. (You should consider the possibility of failure in processing.)
4. When status is 3, the job has been completed.

Your threads should contain logic such that it only picks up jobs for whom the status is 0 and changes the status to 1. This will disallow other threads to pick up those jobs which are under process. When the job completes, the status is set to 3 and if the job fails, the status is set to 2. Then the thread can move on and look for another job that is still to be completed.

You could also ask the threads to consider picking up jobs of status 2, but you will have to define logic to specify a finite number of retries.

**EDIT:**

After a [long discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59736/discussion-between-codenewbie-and-part), we stumbled upon the solution together. My above answer is good in a more generalized state when the 'job' is a process that takes some time to complete. But that wasn't the case in the OP's problem.

So the solution that eventually worked was this:

```
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE JobID = (SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE completed = 0 LIMIT 1) LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
UPDATE Jobs SET completed = 1 WHERE JobID = (PREVIOUS ID); 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hey and thx for your idea ... Yes I've also thought about such a solution. But ... It might happen (due to the threading and due to the fact that I'm using more that one server producing workers), that just running an SELECT and UPDATE inside a transaction will result in an lost update as 2 or more threads will consume the same job.

Comment: You could add additional logic that queues the available threads, so that simultaneous access of available jobs does not take place. Even when the workers arise from different servers, the case of two threads picking up the same job can be avoided.

Comment: What I want to archieve is, to do that via MySQL ;)
So, I just want to lock a specified ROW for selection/read from other threads/workers without locking the whole table

Comment: What is the server side language? And do you have access to the server side code?

Comment: That should be language independend, as I'm looking for an SQL only solution. But I'm using PHP

Comment: Here I'm going to have to disappoint you and tell you that multi-threading in MySQL is not possible. Check [this link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56522/mysql-multi-threading-for-a-single-query). To work with threads, you have to define the logic at the server side, not at the database level.

Comment: It's clear to me, that 1 query can't be multithreaded. BUUUUT: If 1 server/worker/thread will query the table for jobs to process and pick one, also another server is able to do so...
So both will process the same job with no chance to block each other or tell the other server/worker that the current one is already processed (in worst case that both will read the same row at the same time. So the scheduling process would be worker 1: do select, worker 2: do select, worker 1: update, worker 2 update. In this case both will process the same job).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59736/discussion-between-codenewbie-and-part).