# How to lock row in mysql without blocking?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking, deadlock

I have a table in mariadb where I save links to some RSS feeds:

```
id | url                    | done
------------------------------------
 1 | http://example.com/rss | true
 2 | http://example.org/rss | false
 3 | http://google.com/rss  | false
```

When now one process/worker is updating one of the RSS feeds I want it to *hide* the row from other processes/workers so that they don't do the work twice and deadlock.

Using `SELECT ... IN SHARE MODE` or `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` does not work as the row is still visible and will then be deadlocked by all other workers.

So the next idea was using a transaction which sets a flag on an additional `locked` column:

```
BEGIN;
    // find row and select its id
    SET @id := (SELECT id
    FROM url
    WHERE done = false
        AND locked = false
    LIMIT 1);

    // lock row by setting locked flag to true
    UPDATE url
    SET locked = true
    WHERE id = @id;

    // give us some time to copy and paste this sql in another console :)
    SELECT SLEEP(10);

    // unlock row and mark as done
    UPDATE url
    SET
        locked = false,
        done = true
    WHERE id = @id;
COMMIT;
```

*Following SQL is executed over the [sql](http://godoc.org/database/sql) package for [Google Go](http://golang.org).*

This *does* work as intended but it works by blocking all other transactions. This means when I execute the above sql transaction into two sql consoles at the same time I can see how the later transaction waits for the first to finish.
This effect destroys the complete idea of having multiple worker as they will be synced by the transaction in the end.

**How can I "lock" a row from other transactions without blocking?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` which locks the row from `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operations, but allows the row to be read. Refer [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) for more info. A brief from the documentation is below.

> SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE sets a shared mode lock on any rows that are read. Other sessions can read the rows, but cannot modify them until your transaction commits.
>
> For index records the search encounters, SELECT ... FOR UPDATE blocks other sessions from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE or from reading in certain transaction isolation levels.

Your query returns the same row to all processes/workers and they simply wait for the previous lock to release before placing their own lock on the row. To accomplish the kind of lock you need, replace your `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: I just tried this but it did not work. Do you maybe have some hint how to test it from the CLI so I know the problem is not in my application?

Comment: okay I tried to run `BEGIN; SELECT * FROM url WHERE done = false LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE; SELECT SLEEP(10); COMMIT;` from the mysql client which should give me 10 seconds to do a `SELECT * FROM url` from somewhere else. The result is that the selected row from the transaction still exists in `SELECT * FROM url` so your solution seems not to work.

Comment: Here is a link to [a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427434/2964697) which had a similar requirement. There the select query had an inner subquery. And AFAIK, the issue was resolved in that question. Please try that hack and see if you are able to meet your requirement.

Comment: I will agree with your answer but think that using mysql as work manager went into the wrong directions. I noticed that transactions block each other which will block the workers in the end. I think it will be better to move the work manager into the application logic. See my updated answer for more.

Comment: :) That was exactly my initial suggestion in the previous answer. Yes, shifting the thread management to the application layer is the best course of action in this scenario.