# How to lock rows in a queue?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, locking

I have a use case similar to [How to lock row in mysql without blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25718169/759866), but unfortunately the solution is not what I'm after.

I have a queue table that contains rows to be processed by several, simultaneous workers. Say for example:

```
CREATE TABLE queue (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  done TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Every worker will find a few rows to process:

```
SELECT * FROM queue WHERE done = 0 LIMIT 10;
```

The problem is that several concurrent workers will get the same rows, which is something I have to avoid at all costs.

I can use a transaction and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, which will prevent other workers from getting the same rows, but will make them block until the first transaction is completed, effectively killing all concurrency.

**Is there a built-in way in MySQL to select only rows that are not currently locked by another connection?**

I know I could tackle the problem by adding an extra column that every process would update with a unique ID to assign a row to itself, but if there's a built-in way, that's *much* better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a concept similar to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`. Unfortunately, that's not an option in MySQL. It is, however, in recent versions of Oracle and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Happy to see that the concept exists, and of course unhappy to see that it's not yet an option in MySQL. Some day, hopefully! I'll do with an extra column and a PID for now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This day has come! `SKIP LOCKED` is [available in MySQL 8](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/), now GA.